# Is it possible to make night light status icon visible when night light is turned off?

Tags: icons

I really like using Night Light, but sometimes I want to turn it off for a few minutes.  But if it's turned off, it's icon disappears from the status menu, and then I have to go into settings to turn it back on.  Is there a way to force the icon to stay on the status menu when Night Light is turned off?

Comment: I wish this was a simple toggle widget

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can force the NightLight icon to stay on the horizontal bar all the time. For that you need to install a gnome extension called Night Light Slider.

You can download it from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/). and configure that extension like [setting a normal gnome extension](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/)

Once you configured this extension you can change the NightLight temperature from the top menu as shown in the picture. So you don't have to turn off night light from the settings anymore. And you can adjust the max-min temperature from the top bar itself without losing the NightLight icon.

**Note**: You have to tun on the night light in the display settings permanently. And it will not be a problem as you can adjust the temperature from the extension slider itself as shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I have the Night Light Slider, but I don't want to just change the color temperature; I want to actually turn off the night light.  I use Giffy Diagrams a lot, and for some reason having the night light on screws with the color selector in that app.  I looked around for a reason/fix, but couldn't find anything, so it would be easier just to be able to turn the night light off for a few minutes when I'm adjusting colors in Giffy

Comment: @LSharkey But changing the slider to gain maximum will give the exact result of turning off the `NightLight`, right ? Anyway please ignore this answer if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Apparently not, as the problem I described with Giffy Diagrams happens whenever night light is on, regardless of what color temperature is set to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3933/toggle-night-light/)
it's a simple toggle in the top-bar